# PIG Script REPLACE with pipe symbol

Tags: replace, apache-pig

I want to strip characters outside of the curly brackets in rows that look like the following.

```
35|{......}|
```

Stripping the '35|' from the front and the trailing '|' from the end.

```
{.....}
```

Initially working on the first 3 characters, I try the following but it removes everything.

```
 a = LOAD '/file' as (line1:chararray);

 b = FOREACH x generate REPLACE(line1, '35|','');

 dump b;
```

Any thoughts appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`|` and `{` and `}` are special characters in regular expressions and the second parameter for `REPLACE` is a regular expression. Try to escape the characters:

```
b = FOREACH x generate REPLACE(line1, '35\\|','');
```

Answer (score 0):

Some more information : If you want to transform data into a more complex form which cant be achieved simply by REPLACE , you can create a Javascript/Java/Jython/Ruby/Groovy/Python User Defined Function (UDF) which takes your data as input and returns the processed data.

### Example of Javascript UDF:

**Pig Script:**

```
 --including the js file containing the UDF
 register 'test.js' using javascript as myfuncs;

 a = LOAD '/file' as (line1:chararray);

 --Processing each line1 by calling UDF
 b = FOREACH x generate myfuncs.processData(line1);
 dump b;
```

**test.js**

```
 processData.outputSchema = "word:chararray,num:long";

 function processData(word){
    return {word:word, num:word.length};
 }
```

To see how UDFs work please check this : [Pig Documentation for UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/udf.html)

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to answer, I'll take a look at User Defined Functions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use REGEX_EXTRACT :

```
REGEX_EXTRACT(line1, '.*(\\{.*\\}).*', 1);
```

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/func.html#regex-extract