# Logic to compare rows in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I need logic for below scenario which needs to be implemented using Pig scripts. Can anyone please help in providing some ideas on how to do this.

Input contains a column groupName with some data like others and unknown. This data needs to be replaced by its previous record data.

Input:

```
 id,groupName
 123,casc0001
 124,casc0002
 125,sale0001
 126,unknown
 127,nave9876
 128,casc0001
 129,sale0002
 130,others
 131,casc0004
 132,unknown
 133,unknown
 134,others
 135,nave1234
```

output:

```
123,casc0001
124,casc0002
125,sale0001
126,sale0001
127,nave9876
128,casc0001
129,sale0002
130,sale0002
131,casc0004
132,casc0004
133,casc0004
134,casc0004
135,nave1234
```

In the above input 126,unknown to be replaced with 125,sale0001. 130,others need to be replaced by 129,sale0002. 132,unknown 133,unknown 134,others to be replaced with 131,casc0004.

--Edit--

I tried lead function in Pig. But it is used only to compare n rows at a time. Which cannot solve this completely.

Another logic which is working, but looking for optimized one.

```
Cogroup for the same data set (like Dataset and Dataset_self)
-Filter Dataset.id=Dataset_self.id or Dataset_self.groupname='others' or     Dataset_self.groupname='unknown'  
-Generate IdDiff like (Dataset_self.id-Dataset.id), CASE when id=id then ( id, group) else (id_self,group) 
-Foreach (group id){  
         ordered = order by id,diff,group;
         limited = ordered limit 1;
         generate limited ;
     }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Are you looking for the REPLACE function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774447/pig-script-replace-with-pipe-symbol

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a complicated problem on a distributed system like hadoop, especially that your file is going to be split between nodes. In your case what if 126 happens to be the first record in a new split. Then you will need to trace the previous file split which is most likely on a different node. Lets say you come up with a MapReduce program to do this, in all likelyhood it would an extremely slow and inefficient way to do it. The solution might be simpler if you are in a single node system where the splittable property of your input format is false, and the nuber of reducers is set to 1. 
In that case you could almost make the argument that a traditional database like Oracle or Terra data might be a better fit for your problem as you have lead or lag functions readily available which could be used to do exactly what u need.