# Replace character in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, azure-hdinsight

My data is in the following format..

```
{"Foo":"ABC","Bar":"20090101100000","Quux":"{\"QuuxId\":1234,\"QuuxName\":\"Sam\"}"}
```

I need it to be in this format:

```
{"Foo":"ABC","Bar":"20090101100000","Quux":{"QuuxId":1234,"QuuxName":"Sam"}}
```

I'm trying to using Pig's replace function to get it in the format I need..
So, I tried ..

```
"LOGS = LOAD 'inputloc' USING TextStorage() as unparsedString:chararray;;" +
"REPL1 = foreach LOGS REPLACE($0, '"{', '{');" +
"REPL2 = foreach REPL1 REPLACE($0, '}"', '}');"
"STORE REPL2 INTO 'outputlocation';"
```

It throws an error.. Unexpected token '{' in expression or statement.

So based on an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774447/pig-script-replace-with-pipe-symbol), I tried:

```
"REPL1 = foreach LOGS REPLACE($0, '"\\{', '\\{');"
```

Now, it gives an error.. Unexpected token '\\' in expression or statement.

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Works for me:

```
REPL1 = FOREACH LOGS GENERATE REPLACE($0, '"\\{', '\\{');
```

In your code you are missing the `GENERATE` and the double quotes at the beginning and end are wrong.

Comment: Thanks, your code works.. What do I do to change \" to "

Comment: I meant {\"QuuxId\":1234,\"QuuxName\":\"Sam\"} to {"QuuxId":1234,"QuuxName":"Sam"}

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code.

```
LOGS = load 'inputlocation' as unparsedString:chararray;
REPL1 = foreach LOGS generate REPLACE($0, '"\\{', '\\{');
REPL2 = foreach REPL1 generate REPLACE($0, '}"', '}');
STORE REPL2 INTO 'outputlocation';
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: What about  {\"QuuxId\":1234,\"QuuxName\":\"Sam\"} to {"QuuxId":1234,"QuuxName":"Sam"}

Answer (score 0):

Load the data using the delimiter as shown below:

sam = load 'sampledata' using PigStorage(',');

sam1 = foreach sam generate $0,$1,CONCAT(REPLACE($2,'([^A-Za-z0-9:"{]+)',''),REPLACE($3,'([^A-Za-z0-9:"}]+)',''));

This will give you the desired output.

({"Foo":"ABC","Bar":"20090101100000","Quux":"{"QuuxId":1234"QuuxName":"Sam"}"})

Comment: Thanks, will check, I had asked this a long time back. What does PigStorage do? I was using unparsedString:chararray, Also what does $0,$1, $2 and $3 denote in ur sample code..

Comment: PigStorage loads the data from source using the delimiter specified. $0,$1,$2 etc. denote the positional name of the columns. This happens when we do not specify the schema during the load.