# How to extract particular word from list of string in column

Tags: apache-pig

I am having below data in table.

```
Archer late
Patrick late
Marie Walter late
Michael-d'souza late
```

I want to remove late from this list using pig? can i use `regex` to remove the word. Can someone help me to sort this out?

Edited:

I've used below command but failed:

EXTRACT(surname,'(\b[Dd]+[Ee]+[Cc]+[Ee]+[Aa]+[Ss]+[Ee]+[Dd]+\b)'))

Comment: please try to add what you tried in your question. below answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470995/replace-character-in-pig

Comment: I've updated my description.

Answer (score 0):

How aboutcalling REPLACE?

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS (a0:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(a0, 'late','');
dump B;
```